# How to configure Titanium Mobile Studio to work?

Tags: android, titanium

It will sound silly, but I've installed Titanium Mobile Studio on my PC, following its in-depth guide [from here](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Mobile+Web+Support.)

I also have configured Andrid SDK correctly and set my PATH variable to include jdk-path, which have jarsigner,javac. But when I am running the project Kitchen Sink, its giving me following errors in console: 
**Required jarsigner not found**
**Required javac not found**
**Required java not found**
**One or more required files not found - please check your JAVA_HOME environment variable**
Can anyone resolve this??

Comment: which operating system do u use ?

Comment: I am using Windows XP Service Pack -3.

Answer (score 2):

According to my knowledge cause of this type of errors in titanium are,

- IF you are using java version 64 bits than this type of error may occur because titanium works on 32 bit only.
- Java version should 1.6.*. Titanium not supporting java version 1.7.*. If you using 1.7.* java version than give a try to last update of 1.6.*
- Java path setting is incorrect. try to check using java -version.

Comment: So, what ultimately I made it working is: (1) First I set my JAVA_HOME variable to direct to jdk home directory without space in its path. (2) I several time restart the Titanium to make it into effect, but couldnt. So Finally I restarted my machine and Miracle. The First demo application of Tab Activity is now working. But still Kitchen Sink application is not. So can you guide me for it?

Comment: For kitchen sink application i think you should use API's version of android SDK. Not simple version. Cause google maps requires google apis.

Comment: I have already configured the target of Kitchen Sink to Android API 2.2. But when I try to run, sometimes it gives error like INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE and sometimes 'Unable to open database file.' For that, I've gone through FAQ of appcelerator website. But the solutions regarding Antivirus disabling are ridiculous. Also I dont have any antivirus installed on my PC. So what can be the possible solution for it to work. I just want to run this Kitchen Sink application anyhow..

Comment: i think you should give a try to android APIs 2.3.*. Still don't work than i will not be helpful :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you set JAVA_HOME with environment variables. If not please follow this link and and try running app again,

http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows

Comment: I tried, and set JAVA_HOME variable to "C:\Progra~1\jdkxxx", and checked its path from command prompt by entering "echo %JAVA_HOME%". Its displaying correctly. But still I am getting the same error as above mentioned in the question. :(

Comment: @YuAndroid, have you checked that the jarsigner is in the Path?